# java properties において、同じ key を記述した場合、何が起こる？

Tags: java

Java においては、 properties ファイルが、 key-value 的な設定の記述の際に、よく利用されると思います。

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html

このプロパティファイルにおいて、同じキーに対して、複数個のエントリーがあった場合には、これはどういう取り扱いになるのが正しいのでしょうか。取り扱いとして、考え付くのは:

- 未定義
- フォーマットとして不正で、読み込んだら例外が投げられる
- 後勝ち/前勝ち

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Properties.load(...)`はハッシュに逐次格納しています。キーの存在確認はしていません。従って、後勝ちになります。もちろん自前でload()を書けば配列として扱うなど自由にできます。